# Sharepoint to generate the email but doesnt want to send

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email, outlook

I am using SharePoint designer 2010, and need to set up a workflow to function as follow-

When a new item is created in a list, it will generate an email in outlook, but not send (so the email can be modified).

and

When an existing item is modified in a list, it will generate an email in outlook, but not send (so the email can be modified).

Comment: that functionality doesn't exist in a designer workflow

Answer (score 1):

The workflow (*SharePoint SMTP service*) sends the email to Exchange; Outlook has nothing to do with it.

If you want a messaging process where the user can prepare/alter the message you have to built it in a SharePoint List.

- Make the first workflow create a new (message) item in another List (Messaging).
- Direct the user to that list (the Edit Form of the created Item)
- Attach another workflow to this Messaging List which actually sends the email